# python with statement one liner returns invalid syntax

Tags: python

I have a snippet below.. Basically, my goal is to execute my whole python snippet with just one line... But it always returns an error when it comes to the `with` statement

```
$ python
>>> import os
>>> phone = os.environ['PHONE'];
>>> api_id = os.environ['API_ID'];
>>> api_hash = os.environ['API_HASH']
>>> from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
>>> from telethon import functions, types; with TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash) as client: print('test')
```

**With the code above it will return something like below:**

```
>>> from telethon.sync import TelegramClient;  with TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash) as client: print('$2')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    from telethon.sync import TelegramClient;  with TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash) as client: print('$2')
                                               ^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**UPDATE:**
If you guys want to know the whole snippet used with bash level. Feel free to check snippet below:

```
docker exec ${item} python manage.py shell -c "import os; \
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient; \
from telethon import functions, types; \
phone = os.environ['PHONE']; \
api_id = os.environ['API_ID']; \
api_hash = os.environ['API_HASH']; \
with TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash) as client: \
    result = client(functions.channels.JoinChannelRequest(channel='$2'));\
    result2 = client(functions.channels.JoinChannelRequest(channel='$3'));\
"; 

Above is the whole code including the one used in bash script if you are interested to specifically
```

Comment: Replace the semi-colon with a newline.

Comment: Like this? `from telethon.sync import TelegramClient\n  with TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash) as client: print('$2')`

Comment: "my goal is to execute my whole python snippet with just one line.": why so?

Comment: @9769953, I will use it later for bash scripting

Comment: You might still be better off writing a proper Python script, especially if it grows: at some point, you simply can't write a Python one-liner.

Comment: You're not doing anything with `client` though in the block. If your intention is to use `client`, could you please show how? (At the moment, you're just printing `"$2"`, for which you don't need the `TelegramClient` import.)

Comment: `docker exec ${item} python manage.py shell -c "import os; from telethon.sync import TelegramClient; from telethon import functions, types; phone = os.environ['PHONE']; api_id = os.environ['API_ID']; api_hash = os.environ['API_HASH']; with TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash) as client: result = client(functions.channels.JoinChannelRequest(channel='$2')); result2 = client(functions.channels.JoinChannelRequest(channel='$3'));";`

Above is the whole code including the one used in `bash` script if you are interested to specifically know

Comment: Oof: hard to read. Could you [edit] your question and add it to it, that'll be clearer?

Comment: It seems to be with running a python shell from a Django container?

Comment: There are `result` and `result2` as the outcome of a `client` operation. But nothing is done with those two variables? Can they just be ignored?

Comment: @9769953 I think we are going far from the original intention. I will just solve it using a file

Comment: That sounds like a better solution. Though my question(s) were actually to point out that there seems to be unnecessary things, and that makes already a difference. Also if an answer is looked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only [*simple* statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#simple-statements) may be joined with a `;` on a single line:

> Several simple statements may occur on a single line separated by semicolons.

A `with` statement is a *compound* statement, and as such is not eligible to appear on a line after a `;`.

Based on your update, you may just need to remove the line continuations and the semicolons. You already have multiple *physical* lines; there's no reason to try to create one *logical* line.

```
docker exec ${item} python manage.py shell -c "import os
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types
phone = os.environ['PHONE']
api_id = os.environ['API_ID']
api_hash = os.environ['API_HASH']
with TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.channels.JoinChannelRequest(channel='$2'))
    result2 = client(functions.channels.JoinChannelRequest(channel='$3'))
";
```

You probably should *not* try to embed the shell parameters in the script, but rather pass them as arguments. Not knowing what `manage.py` is, you might try

```
docker exec ${item} python manage.py shell -c "import os
import sys
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types
phone = os.environ['PHONE']
api_id = os.environ['API_ID']
api_hash = os.environ['API_HASH']
with TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.channels.JoinChannelRequest(channel=sys.argv[1]))
    result2 = client(functions.channels.JoinChannelRequest(channel=sys.argv[2]))
" "$2" "$3"
```

Comment: Are you saying that there is no way?

Comment: Yes; it's simply not part of Python's grammar. The only places where `;` is recognized is in the `simple_stmts` rule (which is comprised only of `simple_stmt` elements) and (for some reason) the `del_stmt`, which can be terminated with a semicolon for some unknown reason.

Comment: I guess I will just use a file instead

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada That's a good idea for a lot more reasons other than the fact you can't do it this way.

Comment: OMG! Your updated answer worked! I never knew it can be done like that